# Javascript Get Value Without Page Regresh

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<span id="my-points">500 points</span>
```

I am able to retreive the value to console using JS:

```
document.getElementById('my-points').innerText;
```

The value is shown as 500 points (so far so good)

When the score board changes (from 3rd party server), when I run the JS command I get the old points value, I have to refresh the entire page and the value will be updated (visually on client side webpage as well).

Is there a way I can get the server-side value (even if the value is not updating prior to refresh on client side) without actually refreshing the page?

Comment: `document.getElementById('my-points').innerText` will always return the current text, there must be another problem. Can you show us the page or some code?

Comment: Of course it isn't updated, since that would require communication between the browser and the server. You can fetch data from the server in javascript using a `XMLHttpRequest` or the `fetch` API. If you use a framework such as jQuery, lodash, Angular or React, they provide their own APIs, too.

Comment: I do not have access to the server, I only have a web browser, the website is also public and not created by me, I am just a registered user trying to pull this information repeatedly over a defined perod of time